# How to release the memory after CoreML model prediction

Tags: coreml

I'm developing the iOS app with CoreML.
In this app, the class that contains the CoreML model prediction is instantiated for many times. The amount of memory usage accumulates every prediction and it leads the memory leak and crash app.
My question is that how should I release the memory after prediction.

I tried to update the variable that stores the model object after prediction. This effectively reduces the memory usage, but GPU acceleration does not work.
Are there any solution about this problem?

Comment: Please create a minimal code example that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans: I am having a same problem, can you please  help me to check this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67364197/coreml-memory-leak-in-ios-14-5